# How to copy a screenshot and save it to folder as well?

Tags: macos, screenshot

I’m using default macOS utility for screenshots. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to take screenshots.

It gives an option to either copy the screenshot to the destination folder or to save it to clipboard. But I want to do both.

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: When you start the screen shot tool, the image should be in your clipboard. That is how the process starts. Once you have edited and otherwise managed your image, then save it to the folder your wish. Keep save to folder in your hands to prevent lost files.

Comment: I know I can do it all manually. I want to automate it as much as possible, so I want to save it to clipboard as well as to the folder to keep track of my screenshots

Comment: @John - no, it's save to disk by default. It's not like Windows, it has to be told specifically to send to the clipboard. There's no native way to do both at once. You could limp along with doing 2 snaps, one to each, otherwise you'd have to do it by Applescript or find a 3rd party app to do it. If you're screensnapping an entire window, then Cmd/Shift/4 then Cmd/Ctrl/Shift/4 would be quicker, but if it's a selection, the '4' version doesn't remember the last selected area.

Comment: & just to be more awkward, the Screenshot.app itself is faceless & has no Applescript Dictionary. It does have entries accessible through `defaults read/write` in Terminal, but that would require you quit between shots anyway. The older `screencapture` is still scriptable, or can be used from Terminal… but it is the equivalent of the '4' command [which used to be the now vanished Grab.app] & also doesn't remember the last selection - see https://ss64.com/osx/screencapture.html

Answer (score 1):

To save the screenshot to a folder, first open it in Preview.app by clicking the “Share” button.

In Preview, press “File > Save...” and you can save it to any folder from there.

As for copying it: In Preview, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and it should be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: That's rather a lot of faffing around, compared even to taking 2 screenshots & changing the format in between. Where does the Share button come from anyway? For Quicklook or Preview it already must be a file.

Comment: Well I know it can be done manually. But I'd rather automate it somehow. With applescript or something. This is what I need.